# Dynamically slicing lists to exclude middle elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of command, `cmds=[['ADD', '1'], ['LOAD', '5'], ['SQR'], ['ADD', '3']]`, that I want to execute selectively, for example (a) cmd excluding cmd[1] (b) cmd excluding cmd[2]

Any suggestions on how I could do this dynamically? As the list length will not always be known

Comment: a) `new_cmds = cmds[:1] + cmds[2:]`

Comment: @Austin I was probably answering (b)

Comment: a) should be `new_cmds = cmds[:1] + cmds[2:]`

Comment: b) should be `new_cmds = cmds[:2] + cmds[3:]`

Answer (score 3):

You could create a little helper function that returns all the commands except the one you want to exclude:

```
def exclude(commands, idx):
    return commands[:idx] + commands[idx+1:]
```

This will return a list with the command at the specified index removed.

Call it like this if you want to exclude command at index 1:

```
exclude(cmds, 1)
```

Note: index is 0-based here.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmds=[['ADD', '1'], ['LOAD', '5'], ['SQR'], ['ADD', '3']],

list slicing can use If you want to choose selectively ,

(a) cmd excluding cmd[1] 
print(cmds[:1] + cmds[2:)
(b) cmd excluding cmd[2]
print(cmds[:2] + cmds[3:])
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this dyamically? For instance, if I didn't know how many command would be in the the list

Answer (score 1):

If there's a criterion for excluding steps, you can use a list comprehension to create a filtered list of commands:

```
new_cmds = [cmd in cmds if 'LOAD' not in cmd]
new_cmds = [cmd in cmds if len(cmd) < 2]
```

Comment: No, just non end elements. Eg. [1,2,3], I want to exclude cmd 2 or [1,2,3,4,5], I want to exclude, 2, then 3, then 4

Answer (score 1):

Without creating new list objects unnecessarily (as slicing does), we can iterate on the input sequence and keep the first and the last one only.

Note: I leave to you the exercise to safeguard the code against an empty sequence and one with a single element

```
def exclude_internals(seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    yield next(it)  # the first element 
    while True:
        try:
            el = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            yield el  # the last element
            break

els = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(list(exclude_internals(els)))
```

produces

```
[1, 5]
```

Of course we can also simply address the first and the last elements directly

```
els = [1,2,3,4,5]
print([els[0], els[-1]])
```